# Leaderboard "No Items"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, gamekit

I'm trying to implement GameCenter to my app. 
This is to show me the GameCenter LeaderBoard but it's shows me: No Items.

```
-(IBAction) ShowLeader{

GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

The user is authenticate and that's show up when i connect.

when i report score in my GameViewController:

```
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
    GKScore* scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"GameHighScore"];

    scoreReporter.value = HighScoreNbr;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;

   // NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];
    [GKScore reportScores:@[scoreReporter] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {


        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        }
    printf("no error: ");
    }];
}
```

This shows me no error so i suppose it works.

I already tried with 2 accounts since i saw that on other answer but didn't help.

If you need any more info please comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out myself after reading and viewing tones of video.

if that can help someone who as the same problem:

you need to had your BundleID from Itunes connect to your xcode5 info playlist. 
then it should work.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if `gamekit` is missing from `Required device capabilities` in your plist.